# Pyspark, MongoDB and Missing BSON Reference

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to write a basic pyspark script to connect to MongoDB.  I am using Spark 3.1.2 and MongoDb driver 3.2.2.

My code is:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkSQL").getOrCreate()

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("SparkSQL") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/client.coll") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.coll") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format("mongo").load()
```

When I execute in Pyspark with /usr/local/spark/bin/pyspark --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1 I get:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bson/conversions/Bson

I am very new to Spark.  Could someone please help me understand how to install the missing Bson reference?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution to this? It would be very helpful if you share your experience.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't remember exactly how I solved this.  I think I ended up completely rebuilding my environment.  I had a lot of issues with 3.2.0, so I installed 3.1.2 instead.

Here are my work instructions for the installation on Linux: www.benhalickiconsulting.com/s/Spark-312-on-Linux-Installation-Procedure.pdf

This is how I am submitting the Python job to Spark (which also downloads the MongoDb artifacts):
# STANDALONE
# spark-submit --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1 --driver-memory 6G ./PythonProgram.py

Hope that helps.  Let me know if you still have trouble.

Comment: Thank's a lot for your reply. I found that I need to download another jar files to get the MongoDB connector to work propertly. I downloaded the following files and pass them to spark-submit using --jars switch: bson-4.6.1.jar, mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar, mongodb-driver-legacy-4.6.1.jar and mongodb-driver-sync-4.6.1.jar